# Can i add ocl to ecore with java code?

Tags: eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, emf, ocl

I want to add ocl to my .ecore metamodel with java code. But i cant find any example or tutorial.

So i want to ask is tihs possible or where can i find sample codes?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check [OCLinEcore](https://wiki.eclipse.org/OCL/OCLinEcore)? It allows embed OCL in your ecore model and edit it like a text which may be edited with the aid of syntax and semantic validation and completion suggestions.

This is exerpt from the link:

> OCL can be embedded in Ecore using annotations. Maintenance of these
>   annotations is performed automatically by the OCLinEcore editor ...
>   The embedded OCL becomes active when the appropriate delegate 
>   functionality is specified.

There are three type of delegate functionality:

1. Setting Delegate
2. Invocation Delegate
3. Validation Delegate

Also there are invariants constraints.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: No, this is a part of Eclipse OCL Project.

Comment: When I wrote "no", I did mean this is not a solution provide by me, but Eclipse, Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: I added some details to my answer, you can find more information using a link from there.

Answer (score 0):

I see two alternatives:

1. Use EVL (Epsilon Validation Language), it is included in EMF (Eclipse Modeling Framework). In that way, you just right click .ecore model and create a new EVL Validation (under Epsilon options). EVL syntax is well documented on Epsilon book https://www.eclipse.org/epsilon/doc/book/.
2. Use OCL directly. For this purpose yo need to install OCL component on EMF. So, if you are using Eclipse, Help > Install Modeling Components > Find: OCL. Check the obtained result. Now this tutorial could help you http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.ocl.doc%2Fhelp%2FCompleteOCLTutorial.html.

I wish this could help.